# R: roxygen2, imported packages do not appear in namespace

Tags: r, roxygen2, roxygen

I have a file: import_packages.r in my project, containing following:

```
#' @import reshape2
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import DESeq2
#' @import geneplotter
#' @import survcomp
#' @import gplots
#' @import pheatmap
#' @import RColorBrewer
```

When I do `devtools:document()` those packages are not shown in NAMESPACE file and they are not imported in fact.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: sometimes it helps to remove the `NAMESPACE` file, to force to recreate the file again.

Comment: @drmariod did not help. the packages still do not appear in NAMESPACE

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your file only contains the lines that you provided, it is ignored by roxygen2. You should add a line after the roxygen code that contains just `NULL`. So the following should work:

```
#' @import reshape2 ggplot2 DESeq2 geneplotter
#' @import survcomp gplots pheatmap RColorBrewer
NULL
```

I have also reduced the number of lines to show you, how several packages can be imported with a single use of `@import`. But it does not matter for roxygen, on how many lines you distribute the packages.

I think the reason for this is that the roxygen sections must be associated with some R object. For example, the documentation of a function is associated with the corresponding function object. Since you don't want to have the imports associated with a function, you can associate them with `NULL`, which is an R object as well.

As [hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) rightly points out, it is not recommended to fully import that many packages because you might end up with name conflicts. The following two alternatives are usually better:

- Reference function with their explicit package name and the `::` operator: `reshape2::melt()` This has the added advantage that you immediately see, from which package a function comes.
- Import only the functions that you need from a package using `@importFrom`:

  ```
  #' @importFrom reshape2 melt cast
  ```

You can find more information [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports).

Comment: Also worth noting that fully importing many packages is not recommended practice.

Comment: @hadley Thanks for the input. I'll add a few words about the better practices later.